# Redundant null check

Tags: java, eclipse

Following code:

```
  public void test()
  {
    @Nullable T first = null;
    Graph<T> cycleG = new Graph<>();
    ArrayList<Graph<T>> segments = GraphFactory.makeSegments(this, cycleG);
    Graph<T> seg = segments.get(0);
    for (T v : cycleG.vertices)
    {
      if (seg.hasVertex(v))
      {
        if (first == null) // redundant null check here
        {
          first = v;
        }
      }
    }
    assert first != null;
  }
```

gives me a "redundant null check" warning at the indicated line. "T" is a type parameter, the class definition is

```
public class Graph<T extends Comparable<T>> implements IGraph
```

Is this a bug? A known one? Or am I overlooking something. Any tips on avoiding it?

Note: this code does not make sense, it is just a small subset that reproduces the problem. Using 'first' after the loop does not remove the warning.

This is java 8, Eclipse Luna 4.4.1.

Comment: You are declaring it as `null` and nothing else overrides it between the declaration and the check.  You don't need to check for null, since you (yourself) declared it as such.

Comment: @ochi this is only true in the first iteration

Comment: Program name and version that produces this warning should be added.

Comment: sorry, mis-read the statemetnt

Comment: @ochi: Since the first time is null, it WILL get assigned the value of v! That is the whole point of this if.

Comment: Even if it would be assigned the second time - This is "runtime" Logic. I believe the validator causing this *Warning* does not mind about runtime. - viewen as static code, the null check is obsolete due to the first comment of ochi.

Comment: Can you prove that `cycleG.vertices` won't return any null values?  Or that `seg.hasVertex(null)` will not return `true`?

Comment: @ochi kindly remove these comments. it's getting bizarre.

Comment: Are you simply trying to get a non null value out of the segment?

Comment: There is a semantic difference between the versions with and without the "if (first...". Without it, the last v is returned. With it, the first v is returned. The other questions asked in the comment here seem irrelevant. Do not try to make sense of the code, I told that it is just a small thing reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a case of [Eclipse bug 467482](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467482).

Sometimes the code analysis warnings like this do have false positives, particularly in tricky loops, but a small tweak to the code can cause such false warnings to evaporate. Alternatively, decorating the method with `@SuppressWarnings("null")` will shut it up.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Although this loop is hardly tricky :)